# Can't select text in a webpage

Tags: asp.net, html, css, xml

I just created this webpage:

http://nces.ed.gov/datalab/

Then go to quickstats and agree to the terms.

But for some reason I can't select text from this webpage?  Any ideas?

Comment: Go to http://nces.ed.gov/datalab/ and click on Quickstats, then agree to the terms

Comment: prior to agreeing, you can select text but not on the pages afterward

Comment: Still blank page. I've tried with FF and Opera.

Comment: Chrome displays: **Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.**

Comment: try it with noscript plugin for firefox.. works fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of this script.

```
 function mouseDown(ev) {
            ev = ev || window.event;
            var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
            if (target.type == 'text' || target.type == 'checkbox' || target.type == 'radio' || target.type == 'submit' ||
            target.type == 'reset' || target.type == 'button' || target.type == 'file' || target.type == 'image' ||
            target.type == 'select') {
                // Do Nothing
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and

```
document.onmousedown = mouseDown;
```

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/MJTnA/)

Answer (score 1):

If you disable JavaScript in your browser, you'll be able to select, copy & paste any text on the page. However, you may lose functionality on the page until you [enable JavaScript in your browser](http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/answer.py?answer=12654).

Many sites [like this] also will try to prevent a right mouse click and disable the browser's contextual menu, which is how many people copy text to the clipboard.

Photo sharing sites are notorious for this behavior in the hopes of preventing people from downloading and saving images.